# At most one positive entry in each column: How to write this in a mathematical way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, index-notation

Let $\mathbf{X} =(x_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J}$ a matrix and $\mathbf{x}_j$ be its $j$th column vector.

Statement : There is at most one positive entry in each column vector of $\mathbf{X}$ and 0 otherwise. If there is a positive entry, denote the index of that entry as $I(j)$ (or any notation is possible).

How can I represent this statement with mathematical notation?

This was my trial.
\begin{equation}
    H(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle \infty, & x < 0 \\ 
                  0,& x = 0\\
                  1, & x > 0
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        SH(\mathbf{x}_j) = {\sum_{i=1}^{I} H(x_{ij})} 
\end{equation}

Statement : $SH(\mathbf{x}_j) \leq 1, \forall j, 1 \leq j \leq J$

I'm not sure about the infinite part, and I think there is a better notation. As I'm new in mathematical writing, any ideas or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need $H(x)=\infty$ if $x<0$. In this case, $H(x)=2$ suffices :)

Comment: So the matrix consists of all zeros, except at most one non-zero entry per column, and that entry (when it exists) must be strictly positive?

Comment: @IsaacRen $H(x)=2$ would be enough. Thanks :)

Comment: @JackM That is exactly what I want to formulate in a mathematical way!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I can think of two interpretations.

(1) If you're looking to translate the property into a mathematical formula, you can say
$$\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,J\},\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,I\},\;x_{ij}\geq 0,$$
and
$$\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,J\},\;\#\{i\in\{1,\ldots,I\}\mid x_{ij}>0\}=1.$$

(2) If you're looking for a function $f$ such that $f(\mathbf{X})=0$ iff it satisfies the property, then consider that $\mathbf X$ satisfies the property iff $\forall i,j,\;x_{ij}\geq 0$ and
$$\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,J\},\;\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Ix_i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^Ix_i,$$
so we can set
$$f(\mathbf X):=\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Ix_i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^Ix_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i,j}|x_{ij}|-x_{ij}\right)^2.$$
Okay, it's not very pretty, but it gets the job done :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be more exact, I want to formulate 'The other property of $\mathbf{X}$ holds iff this property holds.' So I think (1) is more close to my intention.

Comment: I have two additional questions regarding the answer. First, How can I define the indices of positive entries in (1)? Second, It must be assumed that $\forall i,j,x_{ij} \geq 0$ so (2) is correct, right? For example, if $\mathbf{x}_1 = (-1, 2, 2)^T$, $f(\mathbf{X}) = 0$ but does not satisfy the property.

Comment: For (1), you can define the indices of positive entries as $\{i\in\{1,\ldots,I\}\mid x_{ij}\geq 0\}$. For (2), you are correct, I was trying to find a counter-example but I guess I missed that one x)

Answer (score 0):

Your formulation is correct (as noted in the comments you can take $H(x)=2$ rather than $\infty$ when $x<0$), however, as you have probably noticed it is extremely complicated and hard to understand, essentially requiring the reader to decipher what you mean. You should almost certainly just write what you mean in English. The plain-english formulation in your question is a little hard to understand, but this is more a matter of slightly sloppy writing than of not having written everything in mathematical formulae. You could write:

> The matrix $X$ has non-negative entries with at most one strictly positive entry per column. If the $i$-th column contains a strictly positive entry $x$, denote the row-index of that value by $I(i)$.

Comment: I agree that it could be more complicated to formulate mathematically. Thank you for the clear writing!